# EntLib 5 transaction error

Tags: transactions, enterprise-library

I'm using Enterprise Library Data Access Block with transactions but when I call other method (select command) in Transaction Code Blocks  I get  timeout error because transaction lock the db.

How can I call select command in transaction?

My Code:

```
 dbConn.Open();
 using (dbConn)
 {
     using (dbTrans = dbConn.BeginTransaction())
     {
         try
         {
             var cmd = dbClass.GetStoredProcCommand("Test_Insert");
             dbClass.AddInParameter(cmd, "@No", DbType.String, "Test");
             dbClass.AddOutParameter(cmd, "@ReturnValue", DbType.Int32, 4);
             retval = dbClass.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd, dbTrans);
             if (retval > 0)
                retval = Convert.ToInt32(dbClass.GetParameterValue(cmd, @ReturnValue"));
              var dsDetail=GetDetail(retval); **<-- Error Line i waiting long times and get timeout error**
           dbTrans.Commit();
        }

    }

 }

 private DataSetGetDetail (int TestID) 
 {  
     var TestSql = "Select * from
     TestTable Where ID="+TestID;  
     var cmdTest = dbClass.GetSqlStringCommand(TestSql); 
     var dsTest= dbClass.ExecuteDataSet(cmd); 
     return dsTest;      
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are starting a transaction, performing an insert, and then trying to perform a select using a **different** connection.

Since it's a different connection the select does not participate in the original transaction.  This is causing the select to be blocked by the outstanding transaction.

The way around this is to include your select in your transaction.  Simply pass the transaction:

```
 private DataSetGetDetail (int TestID, DbTransaction dbTrans) 
 {  
     var TestSql = "Select * from
     TestTable Where ID="+TestID;  
     var cmdTest = dbClass.GetSqlStringCommand(TestSql); 
     var dsTest= dbClass.ExecuteDataSet(cmd, dbTrans); 
     return dsTest;      
 }
```

An alternative approach would be to use [System.Transactions and use a TransactionScope](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/01/27/transactionscopedataaccessapplicationblock.aspx).  If you went with that approach you wouldn't have to pass transactions around to your methods.

Or you could commit the transaction and then perform the select if that suits your requirements.